# The plugin `advance_pdf_viewer` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding even latest version added pubsec

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, deprecated

Important thing is i have upgraded flutter version in between and warning was shown up
(until it was performing nicely)

This is warning message but for that I have performed fllowing things

1. updated Manifest with

```
       android:name="flutterEmbedding"
       android:value="2" />
```

2. Firstly `flutter clean`
3. then `flutter update`
4. Perform `flutter pub cache repair`
5. Perform `invalidate cache and restart android studio`
6. Perform `deleted .gradle folder`
7. It was not correct but deleted `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java` for rebuilding plugins file

Still warning persist all above steps was copied from **stackoverflow and GitHub**

Does it caused by copying plugin from git to my project root directory that may be not correct but i have performed that also.

Comment: This method is not working. The changes you have mentioned above are already done in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think 3rd command must be `flutter upgrade` rather than `flutter update`.

I don't have enough points to comment, so added an answer.

Comment: No, I have tried that too for checking my `flutter SDK` and `dart SDK upgrade`, `flutter pub outdated` also checked for making sure any other errors are there.
Now finally I make the conclusion that this is a developer side issue, So, I have reported it to the plugin owner in GitHub.

Comment: yes you are right. `flutter update` is no longer working. `flutter upgrade` is in use. to upgrade it forcefully use `--force flag`